# AKS Nginx internal ingress resource returns connection timeout

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

So Basically I created an internal ingress controller using the following pattern:

`helm upgrade --install internal-ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --create-namespace --namespace internal-ingress-basic --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz --set controller.replicaCount=4 --set controller.service.internalTrafficPolicy=Cluster,controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local -f .\internal-ingress.yaml`

internal-ingress.yaml

```yaml
controller:
  ingressClassByName: true

  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx-internal
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx-internal"

  service:
    external:
      enabled: false

    internal:
      enabled: true
      loadBalancerIP: 10.0.46.0
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

with this I have an internal nginx ingress controller. Now I created an ingress resource that points to an existing **working** service from grafana that already has a functional public ingress (this was just for test purposes)

grafana-internal.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-internal-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: grafana-internal-ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 16k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'

    # This I tried after everything else failed but still nothing changed
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.google.com;
        proxy_set_header Host www.google.com;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      }
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
  rules:
    - host: monitoring.internal.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: prometheus-grafana
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

The ingress successfully gets the **10.0.46.0** loadbalancer IP and **monitoring.internal.domain.com** successfully resolves to that ip but when I try accessing it, I just get a connection timeout.

After that, i tried doing a redirect to google using the proxy pass you see in the annotations and I get the same thing.

There are absolutely no errors in the ingress controller even when putting the controller in **--v=5** to debug.

I'm basically stuck at this point, does anyone know what exactly is happening here?